# Delete whole 3d array if contains any nan

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have a set of images represented by a 3d ndarray. Abstractly what I want to do is, delete an entire image if any of its pixel values is a nan.
Imagine we got the following ndarray:

```
a = np.arange(18).reshape(3, 2, 3)
a = 1.0 * a
a[0][0][1] = np.nan
a[1][0][0] = np.nan
a
[[[ 0. nan  2.]
  [ 3.  4.  5.]]

 [[nan  7.  8.]
  [ 9. 10. 11.]]

 [[12. 13. 14.]
  [15. 16. 17.]]]
```

Now what I want to get is a function that given that ndarray returns True, True, False. In order to finally use np.delete.

I have try the following, which works:

```
np.delete(a, [np.isnan(image.flatten()).any() for image in a], axis=0)
array([[[12., 13., 14.],
        [15., 16., 17.]]]))
```

However, I find it hard to believe that there isn't a function in numpy that is more efficient, and since I have a lot of images I would like to optimise it as much as possible.

Comment: `a[~np.isnan(a).any(axis=(2,1))]`

Comment: That actually works, thank you so much sir!.

Comment: How large are your images, what's the probability of an image having nan, and if it does, how many nans usually?

Comment: Actually, I don't have nans in the images, but when I detect that they are corrupted while creating the dataset, I set the corresponding position of the dataset to nan, and at the end of the creation of the whole dataset, I delete it. The number of corrupted images is minimal, less than 1%.

Comment: Hmm, what does "corresponding position of the dataset" mean, and could you instead just set the True in that list that you want to be True, True, False?

Comment: Imagine I have a set of paths 'image1.npy' ... imageN.npy', now what I do is open them as npy and check if they are corrupt. If they are corrupt dataset[i] = np.nan, if not, dataset[i] = npy. About your second question, i don't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already answered by Michael Szczesny, more Pythonic way would be:

```
filtered_images=a[~np.isnan(a).any(axis=(2,1))]
```

If that piece of code is hard to understand, then consider extracting each image with a for loop as follows:

```
filtered_images=list()
for value in a:
  if(np.isnan(value).any()!=True):
    filtered_images.append(value)
```

Both approaches should give you similar output!

Comment: @PranavHosangadi OP says it's a set of "images". If they're let's say at least one Megapixel large, is this still *significantly* faster? Or is that Python loop insignificant then?

Comment: Yes, the first approach is faster than the 2nd approach, I tested both of the approaches and there is a 0.001-sec difference (the first one is 0.001 sec faster) between both for a 3d array containing three 2d images/arrays.

So, for a large 3d array, I think it would add up to be quite slower! But, should be fine for small dataset or one time pre-processing type of work!

Comment: Bit odd to talk about pythonic and then write `if(...!=True):`...

Comment: @SadmanSakib How large were the images in your test (and how many images?), and what were the two times? If they were let's say 5.000 seconds and 5.001 seconds, that's not significant.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I multiplied all three dimensions by 100, and the first method seems to be about [six times **slower**](https://tio.run/##XVDBasQgFLz7Fa8ndRtEk0tZ8C96C1JeWLMrbIyoKc2lv55qElqoiM83M47DC2t@zL7btjHOE2Q3WZfBTWGO@ewISTYvQVNKyUn4ZQorYAIfCIIuRWBEf7dMvcl9cRFtemCwrJOygbYe5cZ3uRISLoAEe2nqVubw8OgLpswB/2H1Z4KaYv9dEJcKxpAL9CvDL5c0axvFuaFk2EOO7plttLcPN@HdJv10KTNOxjnCJz4XC84DXgmAG9mv384cnvxFv8fSVAnAPzeBIVh/O/VHtOqcqmuPzWAuXX2YS/xjfiw1sE@wqXMbbNSKF0GIzmeWCydSji4w3l9baV6pEILybfsB). Did I make a mistake there? (Quite possible, as I'm a NumPy newb.)

Comment: @KellyBundy interesting, I don't see anything wrong with your code after a quick glance. I guess I was mistaken. I'll take a better look in a bit.